# Changing UIButton title or set UILabel text using for loop

Tags: ios, for-loop, uilabel

I am using this code to change the title of `UIButton` or `UILabel` while the loop is running, but it is not working.

```
- (IBAction)do2:(id)sender
{

    for (float i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 0.5) {

        NSLog(@"%f", i);

        [self.Lbl1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", i]];
        [self.Btn1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }

}
```

The log is printing the value, but the title didn't change. How can I fix this?

Comment: i think it is perfect code. you will be able to see title after completion of for loop. does it shows the title at the end?

Comment: what's the execution time, you can think off.? it does within a fraction of sec, so that mean, you can see(update UI) the final loop execution. You need to try with  NSTimer or something else.

Comment: What were you expecting here? A slow and gradual increment in the title? The operation will be performed so fast (the entire for loop), that visually, you will only see the **last** updated title, provided the label and button are not `nil`. If you are looking for stepwise increment, either use run-loops (blocking), or GCD (non-blocking), or `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. issue with your code is your label and button gets updated with last value of array. the following code would resolve your problem

```
- (IBAction)do2:(id)sender
    {
        for (float i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 0.5) {
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self.Lbl1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", i]];
            [self.Btn1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it change while the application is running like the timer app, you should use Timer for that:

```
NSTimer *timer;//Declare it as a instant variable somewhere

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(changeText)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

And define the method to run in each interval:

```
- (void)changeText
{
    count++;
    [self.Lbl1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", count]];
    [self.Btn1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", count] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if (count >= 1000)
    {

        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is while loop executes fast and you are only able to see title changed after completion of code.

If you want to see title changing try NSTimer instead and change title from the function called from timer. e.g -

```
NSTimer *myTimer    =   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(changeTitle) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
```

And in changeTitle Method -

```
-(void)changeTitle{
    if (GlobalCount <= 1000) {
        GlobalCount++;
        NSLog(@"%f", GlobalCount);

        [self.Lbl1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", i]];
        [self.Btn1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        [myTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

GlobalCount is global integer value.

Comment: It will run forever :) You forgot to increment the GlobalCount in the timer function :)